# How do I ssh into the VM for Minikube?

Tags: docker, containers, virtualbox, kubernetes

What is the username/password/keys to ssh into the Minikube VM?

Comment: OK. Found the ssh info:  username: "docker", password: "tcuser".

Answer (score 261, accepted):

You can use the Minikube binary for this, `minikube ssh`.

Answer (score 93):

Minikube uses boot2docker as its base image, so the default SSH login to the VM ends up being `docker:tcuser`[1](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#ssh-into-vm).

Comment: I showed the vn from virtualbox and as above I used user: docker  pasword: tcuser

Comment: It is deprecated now, and password login is disabled. Login is now available by private public key only, like here: `ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip)` described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913652/1901067 answer from @Bob Van Zant

Answer (score 57):

I too wanted to login without the Minikube command. I found that it drops the SSH key it generates into ~/.minikube/machines//id_rsa.

My machine was named the default "minikube", and therefore I could do:

```
ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip)
```

Answer (score 28):

For windows hyper-v the answer was

- open "Hyper-V Manager"
- right click on the "minikube" VM
- user "root"

There was no password.. that got me in.

Comment: This worked... Thanks (My environment was Fedora + VirtualBox)

Comment: Virtual Box has also only `root`

Answer (score 22):

```
minikube ssh -v 7
```

It will show you the output where you can see the full **SSH** command

```
/usr/bin/ssh -F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -p 56290
```

Comment: For anyone confused - that will take you into the VM for the entire cluster (the "master"?). From there, you can `docker exec -it bash` one of the containers listed in `docker ps`.

Answer (score 7):

All the files mentioned are AuthOptions, which can be configured in the config.json file:

`$HOME\.minikube\machines\minikube\config.json`

Generally, the SSH user is: `docker`.

If you want to ssh into your Minikube node/VM, then use SSH keys. You can use a Windows client application like **[WinSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP)** to configure the keys for your VM. If the format of keys is not as expected (.ppk), then use another client called **PuttyGen** to convert the keys into the expected format.

After you're done, log in using WinSCP, and it will enable you to shh into the desired VM using the configured keys.

Answer (score 7):

Getting user and password for minikube in Mac.

`cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json`

Loggin on SSH

`ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip)`

Comment: Nice! ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) worked in gitbash on windows too :)

Comment: Nice work @Rub21. Your answer helped me when I needed to SSH into minikube on Mac

Answer (score 7):

**docker/tcuser** is the username/password to access to it , and it's also an straight way.

if you just want to master the control platform, then **minikube ssh** is a quick way to login.

Answer (score 4):

Give User Name as - docker
[image]

Give password as tcuser and press enter :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Minikube is running: **minikube start**

Get the Minikube IP address: **minikube ip**

Run the SSH command:

> ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@192.168.59.100

Replace ip with your minikube vm ip address

Answer (score 1):

```
minikube ssh -v 7
```

works for me. This will get to in the ssh docker minikube

```
minikube ssh docker@{IP Address}
```

doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).