# Kubernetes ssh into nodes not working in local

Tags: kubernetes

How to ssh to the node inside the cluster in local. I am using docker edge version which has kubernetes inbuilt. If i run 
 kubectl ssh node 
I am getting

```
 Error: unknown command "ssh" for "kubectl"

Did you mean this?
        set

Run 'kubectl --help' for usage.
error: unknown command "ssh" for "kubectl"

Did you mean this?
        set
```

Comment: [`kubectl ssh` is not a thing?](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3920)

Comment: Whats your KUBERNETES_PROVIDER?. If you are on aws. Use this command to ssh: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/kube_aws_rsa admin@<masterip>`. Check what is the key being automatically generated

Answer (score 1):

There is no "ssh" command in `kubectl` yet, but there are plenty of options to access Kubernetes node shell.

In case you are using **cloud provider**, you are able to connect to nodes directly from instances management interface.

For example, in **GCP**: Select `Menu` -> `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances`, then press `SSH` button on the left side of the desired node instance.

In case of using **local VM** (VMWare, Virtualbox), you can configure `sshd` before rolling out Kubernetes cluster, or use VM console, which is available from management GUI.

Vagrant provides its own command to access VMs - `vagrant ssh`

In case of using **minikube**, there is `minikube ssh` command to connect to minikube VM. There are also other [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870277/minikube-how-to-ssh-into-the-vm).

I found no simple way to access `docker-for-desktop` VM, but you can easily switch to minikube for experimenting with node settings.

Comment: I faced lot of issues with minikube. It does not work with vpn even. so i switched to docker-for-desktop

Comment: It is not related to original question, but anyway. Here are discussions that could help to fix minikube network after VPN starts: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1099    https://gist.github.com/mowings/633a16372fb30ee652336c8417091222

Comment: You switched to  docker-for-desktop .. but... what is the alternative of `minikube ssh`? Not  sure, but it can be `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Answer (score 0):

> How to ssh to the node inside the cluster in local

- Kubernetes is aware of nodes on level of secure communication with kubelets on nodes (geting hostname and ip from node), and as such, does not provide cluster-level ssh to nodes out of the box. Depending on your actual provide/setup there are different ways of connecting to nodes and they all boil down to locate your ssh key, open appropriate ports on firewall/security groups and issue ssh -i key user@node_instance_ip command to access node. If you are running locally with virtual machines you can setup your own ssh keypairs and do the trick..

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively shell into a pod using `exec`(I know its not exactly what the question asks, but might be helpful).

An example usage would be `kubectl exec -it name-of-your-pod -- /bin/bash`. assuming you have bash installed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Although helpful, this answer does not anwers original question of ssh to nodes, not pods.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first [Extend kubectl with plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/) adding https://github.com/luksa/kubectl-plugins.

Basically, to "install" ssh, e.g.:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luksa/kubectl-plugins/master/kubectl-ssh
```

Then make sure the file `kubectl-ssh` is in your path.